# Using reflection to iterate a class properties that has nested classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection

I found this answer here at SO, [Get nested property values through reflection C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188951/get-nested-property-values-through-reflection-c-sharp/37189106#37189106), though when I run it in my case, it also tries to dump/recurse on e.g. a `string`'s property, like `Name`, and when, it throws an exception.

My classes look like this

```
public class MyModels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EditDate { get; set; }
    public string EditBy { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Organization
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Organization()
    {
        Person = new Person();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company : MyModels
{
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Company()
    {
        Organization = new Organization();
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the code from the linked answer

```
var objtree = "";
void DumpObjectTree(object propValue, int level = 0)
{
    if (propValue == null)
        return;

    var childProps = propValue.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in childProps)
    {
        var name = prop.Name;
        var value = prop.GetValue(propValue, null);

        // add some left padding to make it look like a tree
        objtree += ("".PadLeft(level * 4, ' ') + $"{name} = {value}") + Environment.NewLine;

        // call again for the child property
        DumpObjectTree(value, level + 1);
    }
}
DumpObjectTree(itemData);
```

---

What I want is to iterate all the properties and check their value.

When I run the above code sample:

- it first finds `Organization`, and recurse
- at 1st level it finds `Person`, and recurse
- at 2nd level if finds `Name`, and recurse
- at 3rd level it throws an exception when it tries to `GetValue` for `Name`

If I remove my nested classes, and run it:

- it first finds `Description`, and recurse
- at 1st level it throws an exception when it tries to `GetValue` for `Description`

---

How do I make it to not try to dump/recurse on properties of type `string`, `datetime`, etc., like e.g. `Name`, `Description`?

The exception message says: `"Parameter count mismatch."`

As a note , the expected output/content in the `objtree` variable is e.g.

```
Organization = MyNameSpace.Models.Organization
    Person = MyNameSpace.Models.Person
        Name = TestName
    Name = TestCompany
Description = Some info about the company...
Id = 1
EditDate = 31/08/2019
EditBy = user@domain.com
```

Comment: 1) do you want to avoid the exception (then please tell us which exception that is, I currently don't see a reason), or 2) do you generally want to avoid dumping framework types or only dump your own types? In that case you could simply filter the types by namespaces or assemblies.

Comment: @RenéVogt I added what I want, and explained what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that `string` has a property named `Chars`. You normally don't see this property, because it's the indexer used when you do something like `char c = myString[0];`.

This property obviously needs a paramter (the index), and since you don't provide one, an exception is thrown.

To filter the types you don't want to recurse you need to extend the first line in the method. For example

```
if (propValue == null) return;
if (propValue.GetType().Assembly != Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
   return;
```

This will only recurse through types declared in your assembly. If you want special filtering you need to adjust it.
Your current specification (*"of type `string`, `datetime` etc"*) is not specific enough to give an exact solution, but I think the idea is clear.

---

Note that this won't prevent an exception to be raised if you declare an indexer in your own classes. So a better way might be to check for indexers directly:

```
foreach (var prop in childProps)
{
     if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Any()) continue;
```

---

Second note: The current code has another flaw: You should keep track of which types you already dumped and abort the recursion when you come across a type the second time. That's possibly the reason for the exception at `DateTime`. A `DateTime` has a `Date` property, which is - hurray - of type `DateTime`. And so your `objtree` string grows infinitly until an `OutOfMemoryException` or `StackOverflowException` is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After adding the `if (propValue.GetType().Assembly != Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())` it no longer recurse on e.g. `Name` and `Description` properties. When it comes to your 2nd note, keeping track on which types been dumped, I can't do that based on the type, as I have several e.g. `DateTime` properties in my classes (not showed here though). It does not recurse on a `DateTime` property though, so not sure how that _flaw_ would cause an exception.

Comment: @LGSon because `DateTime` is not declared in your assembly, it's no longer recursed into.

Comment: @LGSon and not _recursing_ types twice doesn't mean that the value of your times won't be dumped, only the child- values of them would be discarded.

Comment: When you say _`DateTime` is not declared in your assembly, it's no longer recursed into_, I am trying to understand what that actually means...

Comment: The type `DateTime` is declared in mscorlib.dll, not in your code. That's why the if-statement you just added returns instead of trying to dump a`DateTime`'s properties.

Comment: Ahhh...wasn't thinking in that way at all. Thank you for that, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip recursion when:

- Property is a value type
- Property is a string
- Property value contains reference to the object from the previous recursion level (ie, `ParentObject`) so that you don't get a stack overflow exception
- Edit: Also when property is a collection type. If you want to get creative, you can have your recursor iterate through each object in the collection and then recurse through those

This `PropertyInfo` recursor seems to do the trick.

```
[Flags]
public enum PropertyRecursionOverflowProtectionType
{
    SkipSameReference,
    SkipSameType
}

public class PropertyRecursionBot
{
    public object ParentObject { get; set; }

    public object CurrentObject { get; set; }

    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }

    public Type ParentType { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }
}

public static IEnumerable<PropertyRecursionBot> GetAllProperties(object entity,
    PropertyRecursionOverflowProtectionType overflowProtectionType = PropertyRecursionOverflowProtectionType.SkipSameReference)
{
    var type = entity.GetType();
    var bot = new PropertyRecursionBot { CurrentObject = entity };

    IEnumerable<PropertyRecursionBot> GetAllProperties(PropertyRecursionBot innerBot, PropertyInfo[] properties)
    {
        var currentParentObject = innerBot.ParentObject;
        var currentObject = innerBot.CurrentObject;

        foreach (var pi in properties)
        {
            innerBot.PropertyInfo = pi;

            var obj = pi.GetValue(currentObject);
            innerBot.CurrentObject = obj;

            //Return the property and value only if it's a value type or string
            if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) || !pi.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                yield return innerBot;
                continue;
            }
            //This overflow protection check will prevent stack overflow if your object has bidirectional navigation
            else if (innerBot.CurrentObject == null ||
                (overflowProtectionType.HasFlag(PropertyRecursionOverflowProtectionType.SkipSameReference) && innerBot.CurrentObject == currentParentObject) ||
                (overflowProtectionType.HasFlag(PropertyRecursionOverflowProtectionType.SkipSameType) && innerBot.CurrentObject.GetType() == currentParentObject?.GetType()))
            {
                continue;
            }

            innerBot.Level++;
            innerBot.ParentObject = currentObject;

            foreach (var innerPi in GetAllProperties(innerBot, pi.PropertyType.GetProperties()))
            {
                yield return innerPi;
            }

            innerBot.Level--;
            innerBot.ParentObject = currentParentObject;
            innerBot.CurrentObject = obj;
        }
    }

    foreach (var pi in GetAllProperties(bot, type.GetProperties()))
    {
        yield return pi;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
public class RecursionTest
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    public RecursionTest Test { get; set; }

    public RecursionTest ParentTest { get; set; }
}

var rec1 = new RecursionTest
{
    IntValue = 20,
    StringValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};

rec1.Test = new RecursionTest
{
    IntValue = 30,
    StringValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    ParentTest = rec1
};

rec1.Test.Test = new RecursionTest
{
    IntValue = 40,
    StringValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    ParentTest = rec1.Test
};

foreach (var bot in GetAllProperties(rec1, PropertyRecursionOverflowProtectionType.SkipSameReference))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', bot.Level * 2)}{bot.PropertyInfo.Name}: {bot.CurrentObject}");
}
```